# How can I calculate the area of a slice of a superellipse?

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, ellipse

Say I have a superellipse with a given width, height and eccentricity (n). I want to create x horizontal slices of equal height. How can I calculate the area of each slice?

I don't even need exact values for the specific project I'm working on, only close approximations.

Comment: What is the eccentricity of a superellipse ? What kind of slice ?

Comment: I'm new to superellipses, so I'm not sure what the official term is. On the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse), it's just referred to as "n". It's basically the roundness of the edges, though it's not strictly the border radius. I'm not sure what different kind of slices there might be. Maybe "slice" is the wrong word here?

Comment: @Squis `n` is not eccentricity ... that is just the power coefficient (I would call order) the eccentricity is computed from `a,b` semi axises ratio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make integral for area of superellipse slice [like this (4)](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Superellipse.html) and integrate it numerically in needed range instead of `0..a`

[image]

I think that for approximation simple [method of midpoint rectangle](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/%7Echeung/Courses/170/Syllabus/07/rectangle-method.html)s is enough:

for slice interval `y0..y1` choose number of sub intervals `n`, step `h = (y1-y0)/n` and calculate function value (y instead of x) in points `y0 + h/2 + h*i, i = 0..n-1`, then sum these values and multiply sum by `y1-y0`.

Comment: Thanks! This looks exactly what I'm looking for! I don't know if my math skills are quite advanced enough to be able to translate your answer into code, but I'll try :)

Comment: Why not Simpson ?

Comment: Yes, [Simpson's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson's_rule) in good choice for such smooth function integration, and might provide adequate accuracy with evaluation only at endpoints and midpoint at every interval.